# Highlighting angular brackets and their contents if they are at the beginning of a line

Tags: vim

In Vim, how do I highlight (match, to be precise) only the angular brackets and their contents if they are at the beginning of a line, in the following

```
[1-2-A 3.2.1.] Text goes here ... some more text ...  
which then continues here. [This should not be highlighted]
Some more text here.
```

The second pair should not be highlighted.

I'd appreciate any help on this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This short pattern works:

```
/^\[.*\]
```

Long version(if nested brackets are not allowed):

```
/^\[[^][]*\]
```

Non-greedy version

```
^\[.\{-}\]
```

Comment: just some clarification the `^` forces the match to start at the beginning of the line, which I believe is the center of the question being asked.

Comment: Thanks kev. That did it! (The shorter version was good enough already, but the longer version will surely benefit somebody too).

Comment: Note that the first pattern works *only* if there is no text in square brackets later on the same line.

Comment: @ldigas:  Consider using the pattern `^\[.\{-}\]`.  If nested brackets are possible in that line starting block, it cannot be matched simply with a regular expression.  In that case, use `%` motion command or `a[` text object.